# Use Javascript for elements on different page?

Tags: javascript, web, cross-domain

Is it possible to get the number of items in a drop-down with JavaScript on a different page? (Also a different domain)?

If so, how are the legal actions I have to take to be allowed to do this? Is it enough to contact the owner of the other page?

Thanks for your help

Sincerely Juggernaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible in ways that are unquantifiable.

For a start, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Even using cross origin resource sharing, i.e XHRing data from another domain with appropriate "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers this is not possible. 
The HTML DOM, Javascript scope, and form controls for a page are isolated from the DOM, JS and Controls on the other pages.
Browsers like Chrome even isolate these into seperate processes per tab.

Comment: That's too bad, but thank you for the quick and professional answer.

Comment: You could always do it server side.

Comment: Sure that would be a possibility, but sadly I'm not able to work on the server side.

Comment: as in, retrieve the data at some point BEFORE the data is delivered to client.